# Illegal Shadowing (Shadowing let with var)

Tags: javascript, shadowing

Consider the following example of shadowing in JavaScript:

```
let a = 99;                                                                                                             
{
        var a = 10;
        let b = 11;
        const c = 200;
        console.log(a);
}
console.log(a);
```

Here I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
```

But in the following case, there is no syntax error and the code is completely valid.

```
var a = 99;                                                                                                             
{
    let a = 10;
    let b = 11;
    const c = 200;
    console.log(a);
}
console.log(a);
```

In the second case `var a` is declared in global scope and `let a` is in block scope.
But why this is not valid in first case?
There, `let a` will be declared in separate scope and `var a` should be declared in the global scope.
Why this case is invalid?

Comment: There is no block in the first example? You're also changing too much between examples

Comment: The first example is a syntax error. Where is the opening `{` ?

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected it, Thanks:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But why this is not valid in first case?

Because both of those declarations are in the **same scope**.¹ Your second example works because the `let` is scoped only to the block, not to the scope outside the block where `var a` exists. (Just like a local variable in a function.) So in the second example, it's shadowing. In the first example, it wouldn't be shadowing, it would be duplication, which you can't do with `let` (even if the other declaration uses `var`). (You *can* use `var` to declare a variable more than once in the same scope. The subsequent `var`s are ignored, though any initializer on the variable is converted to an assignment. E.g., `var a; var a = 42;` is identical to `var a; a = 42;`)

---

¹ Okay, so technically, it's a bit more complicated than that. `var` variables exist in an "outer" global lexical environment that holds *bindings* (loosely, *variables*) on the global object, but `let` variables exist on an "inner" global lexical environment that doesn't hold its bindings on the global object. Global scope is still just one scope, so as you've seen you can't have `var a` and `let a` both at global scope because they conflict with each other. But there are other ways to create "outer" global variables, such as assigning to a property on `window` (or `this` at global scope, or `globalThis` in modern environments):

```
// At global scope
window.a = 42;    // Creates binding in the outer global environment
console.log(a);   // Shows 42
```

which means it's possible to create a binding in both the outer and inner global lexical environments:

```
// At global scope
window.a = 42;    // Creates binding in the outer global environment
let a = "answer"; // Creates binding in the inner global environment
console.log(a);   // Shows "answer"
```

Since the inner one is closer to the code doing the `console.log(a)`, the above outputs `"answer"`.

Fun fact: Depending on how you count, on browsers there are somewhere between two and *six* layers to "the" global environment.